# ggplot2 why is my smooth function not working?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to produce a simple graph of a dataset via R shiny and ggplot2. While the plot is fine, when I click the check box for smooth, nothing happens to the graph.

I am using `stat_smooth()` here. Another problem (not related to this one) is that even though I added the `options(shiny.maxRequestSize=-1)` to allow users to upload big files, the program still gives me an error when I try to upload something above 5 MB (it just crashes).

Any ideas on this? Here is my code:

ui.R

```
dataset <- list('Upload a file'=c(1))

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  

  
  sidebarPanel(
    

    fileInput('file', 'Data file'),
    radioButtons('format', 'Format', c('CSV', 'TSV')),

    checkboxInput('smooth', 'Smooth')
  )
  
  
  
  mainPanel( 
      plotOutput("plot")
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library(ggplot2)
#Increase max upload size 
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=-1)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

data <- reactive({
    
    if (is.null(input$file))
      return(NULL)
    else if (identical(input$format, 'CSV'))
      return(read.csv(input$file$datapath))
    else
      return(read.delim(input$file$datapath))
  })
  
  observe({
    df <- data()
    str(names(df))
    if (!is.null(df)) {
      updateSelectInput(session, 'x', choices = names(df))
      updateSelectInput(session, 'y', choices = names(df))

    }
  })

output$plot <- renderPlot({ #Basic Plot
    
    if (is.null(data()))
      return(NULL)
 

    p <- ggplot(data(), aes_string(x=input$x, y=input$y)) + 
         geom_point(size = 3) 
    
    if (input$smooth)
      p <- p + stat_smooth()


    print(p)
    
    
  })
       }
```

Comment: Have you checked that your plot works offline with `stat_smooth()`?

Comment: Do you mean on terminal? (I am using R studio). I'm not sure how to test it via the terminal.

Comment: No, I just mean have you made sure that you can get the kind of plot you want using some example data offline, without worrying about running it through Shiny. Just trying to rule out the easy fixes.

Comment: I found the solution, now I know that checking the plot offline is the first thing you're supposed to do... Turns out I need a group = 1 in my aes_string. Terminal told me the error when I tried graphing the function. Thank you!

Comment: @user2649452 Please add your solution as an answer (it's encouraged to do that rather than edit the question) or delete your question.

Comment: Because I do not have enough reputation I cannot answer my own question for 8 hours...Here is my answer for now: Good practice: always try to run your graphs offline (without going through Shiny). I needed a 'group=1' statement inside my aes function of my plot.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, now I know that checking the plot offline is the first thing you're supposed to do... Turns out I need a group = 1 in my `aes_string`. Terminal told me the error when I tried graphing the function.

Good practice: always try to run your graphs offline (without going through Shiny). I needed a `group=1` statement inside my aes function of my plot.